# Comparing date is not working as expected in java

Tags: java, json, date

I am using `compareTo()` for date. It is working as expected in following scenarios.

1. returns -1 and
2. returns 1

But it is not working  in this scenario - > returning zero(0). If both dates are equal then it should return zero right?

```
Actual Date 1 : 2018-04-16T05:30:00.000+0530
Actual Date 2 : 2018-04-16T00:00:00.000+0530
```

Comparing Dates using `compareTo` method

```
Date 1 :2018-04-16
Date 2 :2018-04-16
```

Java returning -1 for this. I have no idea why this happening. I also tried with equals method.
EX : `date1.equals(dat2)` - > Returns FALSE.

**Note : Here Date1 and Date2 is getting by typecasting. I am getting the JSON  date as `1500544580000` (Arbitrary value not exactly given). And then i am comparing the date using java method.**

Example Code

```
Date date1= (Date) somemethod("Date"); //2018-04-16 Date date2= (Date) somemethod("Date"); //2018-04-16

if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0 )    syso(false) else
      syso(true)
```

In above method true should get printed right brother? But it is not working/Printed. I am getting false Because that compareTo method returns -1 instead of returning 0.

Comment: Can you create a short little code example where you create your 2 date objects and compare them? Without knowing any code it is pretty hard to help and even guess what might be going on.

Comment: the date and timezone are equals but not the time (05:30:00.000 vs 00:00:00.000) . It behaves as expected

Comment: The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision. Your dates have the same year, months, day, timezone but different hour and minutes. They are not equal.

Comment: Hi Here is a code

Comment: @benjaminfrank when asked for code example, SO users usually expect an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: **Stop using `Date` immediately.** It has been outdated for many years. You are better off switching to the newer Java Date and Time API available from the `java.time` package since Java 8. See [Arvind Kumar Avinash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62754186/507738).

Comment: `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: Exactly what class are casting from? And what class *exactly* are you casting to? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: What are you using to convert your JSON (like Jackson or Gson, for example)? For certain it can be configured to give you something else than an instance of a poorly designed and long outdated `Date` class?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) which returns the correct result as shown below:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

        // #1
        // Parse the first date-time string to OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-04-16T05:30:00.000+0530", formatter);

        // Create an instance of LocalDateTime with the given date, time and zone offset
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.APRIL, 16), LocalTime.of(5, 30));

        // Get OffsetDateTime from LocalDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt2 = OffsetDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 30));

        // Display the result of comparison
        System.out.println(odt1.compareTo(odt2));

        // #2
        // Parse a date string to LocalDate
        LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.parse("2018-04-16");

        // Create an instance of LocalDate with year, month and day
        LocalDate ld2 = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.APRIL, 16);

        // Display the result of comparison
        System.out.println(ld1.compareTo(ld2));

        // #3
        // Get Instant from the time-stamp of 1523836800000
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1523836800000L);

        // Get OffsetDateTime from instant
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 30));

        // Display the result of comparison
        System.out.println(odt.compareTo(odt2));

        // #4
        // Parse the second date-time string to OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt3 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-04-16T00:00:00.000+0530", formatter);

        // Get the LocalDate from the first date-time string
        LocalDate localDate1 = odt1.toLocalDate();

        // Get the LocalDate from the second date-time string
        LocalDate localDate3 = odt3.toLocalDate();

        // Display the result of comparison
        System.out.println(localDate1.compareTo(localDate3));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: while those examples are correct, this won't solve OP (unsolvable) issue as he is expecting 2 different date-time to be equals

Comment: @jhamon - OP has mentioned `Note : Here Date1 and Date2 is getting by typecasting. I am getting the JSON date as 1500544580000 (Arbitrary value not exactly given). And then i am comparing the date using java method.` and he has given an example code below it. The question is not clear. So, I've put three options which might help OP to proceed. I've been waiting for his/her comment based on which I'll post the required update.

Comment: Added one more option (`#4`). Still waiting for OP's comment/confirmation if the solution has solved his/her problem.